# Is there have any solution to Defer Offscreen Image that used for div Background Image?

Tags: javascript, css, deferred, lighthouse

I'm using an image for div background image and lighthouse warning me for deferring offscreen image. This is my code and Is anyone can say, how can I defer this image with this code?

```
<div class="page-info hasOverly" style="background: url([@url]app/images/bg2.webp); background-size:cover">
```

**Note**: [@url] is my website domain address. And say how can I use CSS for 'lazyloaded' and 'lazyloading' that explained in (https://web.dev/codelab-use-lazysizes-to-lazyload-images/)

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since the question has nothing to do with it. For future reference, only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand.